# In Rails, how do I query two has_many associations in a single finder?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, has-many, finder

I’m using Rails 4.2.  I have the following user model with a couple of has_many associations

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    …
  has_many :roles, through: :roles_users
  has_many :addresses, dependent: :destroy, as: :addressable, inverse_of: :addressable


class Role < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
  has_many :roles_users


class RolesUser < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :role

end


class Address < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :addressable, polymorphic: true
  alias :user :addressable
```

I would like to find all users of a specific role without any addresses.  I thought the below would do it

```
> users = User.includes(:roles, :addresses).where(:roles => {:name => 'User'}, :addresses => {:user_id => nil})
```

But when I check the results, I’m still getting results that have addresses …

```
2.7.1 :012 > users.last.addresses.count
…
 => 2
```

What’s the proper way to write a finder that queries these two has_many associations?

Comment: You could test it using NOT IN `User.where.not(id: User.joins(:addresses, :roles).where(roles: { name: 'admin' }).select(:id))`. If not could you list the users, roles, roles_users and addresses that you have in the database? Also adding the relationships in every model involved in your query to the question.

Comment: Thanks man, that solved it for me.  If you want to include that query as the answer, I'll accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking for children records with a nil parent id is like the way of doing this in Rails 4. But if that doesn't work, you could use the NOT IN clause combination:

```
User
  .where
  .not(
    id: User
          .joins(:addresses, :roles)
          .where(roles: { name: 'User' })
          .select(:id)
  )
```

It's basically filtering out by the user id all those user rows that have an address associated, have a role, and the role name is exactly "User". You end up with a SQL query like this:

```
SELECT "users".*
FROM "users"
WHERE "users"."id" NOT IN (
  SELECT "users"."id"
  FROM "users"
  INNER JOIN "roles_users" ON "roles_users"."user_id" = "users"."id"
  INNER JOIN "roles" ON "roles"."id" = "roles_users"."role_id"
  WHERE "roles"."name" = 'User'
)
```

Comment: Hey, hate to backtrack on my comment, but when I saved your finder method to a var, "users", and then ran "users.find{|u| u.addresses.count > 0}", it returns a result.  If I'm looking up users with no addresses matching a specific role, I woudl expect my find would return nothing.

Comment: No worries. Can you add the info I asked for in the question comment?

Comment: Thanks.  I added the model relationships.  I didn't add the individual values in the database as there were too many but if those are still needed, let me try and figure out a way to come up with ones taht pertain only to this example.

Comment: Ack, please disregard.  All is well.  My find in comments (users.find{|u| u.addresses.count > 0}) didn't account for the specified role.  When I added that in the mix, indeed the results were consistent.